# easy_install not working on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, apt-get, easy-install

I've created an Ubuntu desktop on a flash drive that I've booted via my Mac laptop. I'm trying to install pip, and am having no luck. I've installed the `setuptools` for python, and have updated `apt-get` and all that stuff, but when I go to run `sudo easy_install pip` it's not recognizing the `easy_install` command. Any help would be much appreciated, (especially since I'm using Ubuntu since I was never able to install pip and pygame and numpy to run properly on my Mac because of errors between python 2 and 3).

Comment: Why are you trying to use `easy_install` to install `pip`? That hasn't been the right solution since around 2012 (except for people using Apple's pre-installed Python on 10.6-10.9). Even if you have a truly ancient version of Ubuntu.

Comment: `apt install python-pip` if you want to have `pip` for `python2`, or `apt install python3-pip` for `python3`.

Comment: If you're using your distro's Python, use their `pip` package. If you're using a different Python 2.7.9+/3.4+, use the bundled `ensurepip. If you really need to run Python 2.7.5 or 2.6 or 3.3 or something, use `get-pip.py` as explained [in the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

Comment: @abarnert I tried running that first, but it spit back "unable to locate package pip"

Comment: @MandyLB You tried running _what_ first?

Comment: @abarnert sorry, was kinda replying to 2 comments, I had tried running `apt install python-pip` first

Comment: OK, first: what version of Python do you have? What version of Ubuntu? Is your Python the builtin Ubuntu Python? If not, is it the standard Ubuntu python2 (if you're using a new version that defaults to 3.x) or python3 (if not)? If not, where _did_ you get Python from?

Comment: To pile on to what @abarnert said, the Python version is important. Ubuntu uses Python 2.7 at the system level and you use python, pip etc. as commands If you need to use Python 3.x then you use python3, pip3, etc. as commands. To install pip3 use sudo apt install python3-pip. If you don't need the latest and greatest version of your package, you might be able to install from Ubuntu repostories as sudo apt install python3-<package name>. You can use tab autocomplete to get package name.

Comment: @abarnert it's ubuntu 18.04, like I mentioned in the initial post, it's being run from a flash drive (don't know if that matters). Python is the  one that was already on the system when ubuntu was installed, and it's python 2.7.15 that appears to be the default.

Comment: If you would like to keep your version of pip upto date then `$ sudo easy_install pip` is correct.